# How to configure MultipartResolver?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" 
    id="multipartResolver"> <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000" /> 
</bean>
```

There is my context.xml file but when I include the multipartResolver configuration I get the following error:

```
"cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.".
```

Please help me, I am new to spring.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should prefix `bean` and `property` with `beans`:

```
...
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"> 
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000" /> 
</beans:bean>
...
```

and remember to close the XML with the end tag:

```
...
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: This answer is still valid, and it's because the OP is using a newer version of Spring than the example he copied and pasted from. (Just like me!)